# Specifying full path when inlcuding directories in C++

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction, linker, mingw

In C++ I'm messing with the boost library, and I have the "boost\" directory with all of the boost .hpp files and directories and such in my compiler's include folder at "MinGW\include\boost\". Now what confuses me is that when I want to use the file "lambda.hpp" I have to actually type:

```
 #include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
```

but if I'm including an entire directory such as "boost\algorithm\" I only have to type:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

even though the "algorithm" folder is not in the directory "MinGW\include", it's in "MinGW\include\boost\". 
Why don't I need to give a full path when including whole directories as opposed to individual header files?

Comment: `algorithm` is not a folder, is a STD header FILE, located in the standard C++ default include directory. The `boost/algorithm` folder is another thing, and contains many files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header file `<algorithm>` is part of the standard library, not of Boost.

The paths are relative to a list of paths the pre-processor searches for header files. So in the case of `<algorithm>` there is a file `algorithm` in the root of one of those paths, while in the case of `<boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>` there is another search path that have a subfolder `boost` which has a subfolder `lambda` which has a file `lambda.hpp`.

By the way, all Boost header files have the suffix (i.e. extension) `.hpp` while the standard library header file has none at all.

As for thinking you include the complete directory `algorithm`, the pre-processor doesn't have support for that, instead you have to include the files in the path `boost/algorithm` separately.